# Toggle the nearest content when click on anchor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a content structure like this:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle_button">Click me.</a>
<p class="hidden_content">This content is toggleable.</p>

<a href="#" class="toggle_button">Click me.</a>
<p class="hidden_content">This is a different section.</p>

<a href="#" class="toggle_button">Click me.</a>
<p class="hidden_content">This section is also different.</p>
```

I have already discovered how to make this work with one section, but how can I make it so that when I click on a toggle_button it opens only the nearest hidden_content class.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.toggle_button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p.hidden_content').toggle();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
$("a").click( function(){
   $(this).next('p').toggle();   
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4SJB/9/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with JavaScript but you could also stay with plain CSS with the [:target selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) --

```
<a href="#hiddenContent1" class="toggle_button">Click me.</a>
<p id="hiddenContent1" class="hidden_content">This content is toggleable.</p>

<style>
 .hidden_content{
    display:none;
 }
 .hidden_content:target{
    display:block;
 }
</style>
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qF6pn/)

Answer (score 0):

This will toggle the following div, and stop the page returning to the top:

```
$('a.toggle_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('p.hidden_content').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [jQuery .next() selector](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".toggle_button").on("click", function () {
    $(this).next(".hidden_content").toggle();
});
```